# Current Section handle

Tags: navigation, sections

I want to build a subnav with all entries from the current Section.

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section(getCurrentSection).level(1) %}
```

I'm looking for the handle "getCurrentSection". I will use this for pages in 5 different sections, so I don't want to select the section by hand, like:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('Section 1').level(1) %}
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('Section 2').level(1) %}
......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current section handle from the entry like so

```
{{ entry.section.handle }}
```

Comment: No problems, glad it did the trick ;)